# User defined guard with type predicate still returns property does not exist error

Tags: typescript

In the example below, I've created a `NodeJsProject` type that's a union of `NodeJsApp` and `NodeJsPackage` interfaces.

`NodeJsProject` and `NodeJsApp` both extend `NodeJsProjectBase` because they share common properties but it's important that they can be checked and handled separately.

```
interface NodeJsProjectBase {
    name: string
    packageManager: "yarn"|"npm"
}

interface NodeJsApp extends NodeJsProjectBase {
    projectType: "app"
}

export interface NodeJsPackage extends NodeJsProjectBase {
    projectType: "package"
    npmUrl: string
}

export type NodeJsProject = NodeJsApp | NodeJsPackage
```

`isPackage()` is based on the [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) example in the documentation

```
export const isPackage = (project: NodeJsProject): project is NodeJsPackage => {
    return project.projectType === "package";
}
```

Now that I can check if a `NodeJsProject` is an `NodeJsApp` or a `NodeJsPackage`, this guard should prevent an error when I try to call `project.npmUrl`:

```
return isPackage(project) ? <div> {project.npmUrl} </div> : <div>NA</div>
```

However, even with this guard, calling `project.npmUrl` still produces the error:

```
TS2339: Property 'npmUrl' does not exist on type 'never'.   
The intersection 'NodeJsApp & NodeJsPackage' was reduced to 'never'
 because property 'projectType' has conflicting types in some constituents.
```

[Working typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwjpAhgYwNYHsBuBTAJwDMAbbAdwDp1sBbYAR2AHYBGAJgA4uAGAVhbA2XDiwBsAFg4AoGQEsAdpCLEM%20UADlsAE3wApOAAVC2AFb50kAEKo4GgN4zQL0ItR18CUCkJKA5s6uMBiYqP74ALKo7hGE3gBEAJ6ohIoJAD4JijB0CTIAvnJKKiTqWroGcACCMDCg%20AAeKoo6cBV6hibmljZ2jkEuMKYWVgAqSTBeoAmodflFCsqq5dqdxqHhGk0tbR1V3aN99qBOrqDDPeOT0wkhWFv55zl0AKqEpN6%20AYVykDf7LojXqgAC8gJqdVAGQhRk2ETktEUKAuwKsiFhaMgAG0ALpg0DYoJnVzuTzeADkAAFiNhsMA6EkALT3MIRCkAGkGqKukAmU0SrMeXPOQoi0ViRESKTSCRFpNy70%20MygsEQIAomqoLzMcBo9GAYvwwCpdMwpFQwDNFqZTWG%20DgcCeoAK8pJLjJ02ptPpjKZcxgnO5lyO-NuAblwfhURiW3iMxl6XlRVxiOwyMgoHkGweEQJAAoQ71vGsDliAJTeItWLPtUtdaNggB8p25hHwkAArmlQBSXkqKVnFDyjgBuX4yauQPV0OaFrHN1vnbkgUCQcDZnzgbCd0g6Hk6TvoDQxBqEUyEFdgJEo7ukAlT7WKj5yc6r9ebnTYB1ubCZy6HseoCnkQF6gAARpYqCdic2DEGu4AaP4napDo3I3pmd4EtmcK5vg868uWoAAPwjr0T5vB8oCUhS6HpnA2CkPgVDkP4BFHNqHj4ByoB3uWhT8S4QA)

Comment: The validity of the expression `project.npmUrl` does not depend on the context it occurs in; the fact that it's in a type guard function doesn't matter. It's not clear why you would expect Typescript to recognise the purpose of your function and treat this expression differently as a consequence. What you should do is either give `NodeJsApp` a property like `npmUrl?: undefined`, or write your type guard function as `'npmUrl' in project && project.npmUrl !== undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3, I think I improved the question a bit by adding a `projectType` property to to `NodeJsApp` and `NodeJsProject` based on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions but the guard is not working

Comment: *"The intersection 'NodeJsApp & NodeJsPackage' was reduced to 'never'"* - it's not clear from your code where that intersection type is coming from. Please make sure your code is a [mcve], ideally include a link to the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) with code that produces the error message you're asking about.

Comment: Type guards can only refine the type, not change the type.  Based on the error message it seems like the variable is already known to be type `NodeJsApp` before you call the function, resulting in an impossible union.  You need to figure out where/why that is happening.

Comment: @kaya3 - I added a typescript playground link and it's working as I would expect. I'll keep trying to narrow down why it's not working in my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error specific to my application. I suspect it was a typo because it's suddenly started working. Here is a [typescript playground with the working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwjpAhgYwNYHsBuBTAJwDMAbbAdwDp1sBbYAR2AHYBGAJgA4uAGAVhbA2XDiwBsAFg4AoGQEsAdpCLEM%20UADlsAE3wApOAAVC2AFb50kAEKo4GgN4zQL0ItR18CUCkJKA5s6uMBiYqP74ALKo7hGE3gBEAJ6ohIoJAD4JijB0CTIAvnJKKiTqWroGcACCMDCg%20AAeKoo6cBV6hibmljZ2jkEuMKYWVgAqSTBeoAmodflFCsqq5dqdxqHhGk0tbR1V3aN99qBOrqDDPeOT0wkhWFv55zl0AKqEpN6%20AYVykDf7LojXqgAC8gJqdVAGQhRk2ETktEUKAuwKsiFhaMgAG0ALpg0DYoJnVzuTzeADkAAFiNhsMA6EkALT3MIRCkAGkGqKukAmU0SrMeXPOQoi0ViRESKTSCRFpNy70%20MygsEQIAomqoLzMcBo9GAYvwwCpdMwpFQwDNFqZTWG%20DgcCeoAK8pJLjJ02ptPpjKZcxgnO5lyO-NuAblwfhURiW3iMxl6XlRVxiOwyMgoHkGweEQJAAoQ71vGsDliAJTeItWLPtUtdaNggB8p25hHwkAArmlQBSXkqKVnFDyjgBuX4yauQPV0OaFrHN1vnbkgUCQcDZnzgbCd0g6Hk6TvoDQxBqEUyEFdgJEo7ukAlT7WKj5yc6r9ebnTYB1ubCZy6HseoCnkQF6gAARpYqCdic2DEGu4AaP4napDo3I3pmd4EtmcK5vg868uWoAAPwjr0T5vB8oCUhS6HpnA2CkPgVDkP4BFHNqHj4ByoB3uWhT8S4QA)